# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Home Improvement's [second moderator election](https://diy.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Tester101] [image: BMitch]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://diy.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) shortly - please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/481099/0).

Comment: Congrats to the new mods! And, thank you to everyone who ran. The candidate pool was a tough one, and all of you deserve mention. :)

Comment: Congratulations to BMitch and Tester. Less work for me, yay!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Well done guys. @Tester101 50+ votes. wow... PS where can I download that data file?

Comment: @ppumkin: follow the link, look for the grey box at the bottom of the post.

Comment: i'm sure you guys will do a great job.  Congrats

Comment: Congrats guys, you'll do great!

Comment: Thanks for all the kind words, and a big thanks to the other nominees and everyone that participated in the election.